# Use if exists in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, condition, exists

I know about the exists feature,  but that does not help me with the given situation. What I want is:

Check if some row exists, and **if exists** then check for an another row if    **row exists**.

Here's the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7a94a/12).

Description:

A location table:

```
| ID |   NAME | ADDRESS |
|----|--------|---------|
|  1 | India1 |  (null) |
|  2 | India2 |  (null) |
|  3 | India3 |  (null) |
|  4 | India4 |  (null) |
|  5 | India5 |  (null) |
```

Then a location_flag table:

```
| ID | LOCATION_ID | FLAG_ID | VALUE | PARENT_ID | DELETED |
|----|-------------|---------|-------|-----------|---------|
|  1 |           1 |       1 |   YES |    (null) |  (null) |
|  2 |           1 |       2 |   YES |    (null) |  (null) |
|  3 |           2 |       1 |   YES |    (null) |  (null) |
|  4 |           2 |       2 |    NO |    (null) |  (null) |
```

What I want is to get all locations except location with id=2.

```
In procedure, it'd be like:
if(locationWithFlag1='YES'){
 if(locationWithFlag2='YES'){
//make this row to be appear in result
}
}
else{
//make this row appear in result
}
```

Is it possible without bringing in plpgsql?

Comment: You need to provide a ***lot*** more details than that. Show us the table definition (as `create table`) show us some sample data (as `insert into ...`) and show us the expected output based on that sample data. Ideally create a http://sqlfiddle.com example

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name check this out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7a94a/3

Comment: And what is the expected output? I don't really understand the "*then I want to check for flag_id=2 and value='Yes'*" part.

Comment: I updated again

Comment: @SachinVerma This is similar to your previous question. Just use `where exists (...) and exists (...)` instead of `not exists`

Comment: @ypercube I still want this combination of both exists to be optional and or wont help

Comment: I updated the fiddle

Comment: please check now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7a94a/12

Comment: You should be able to do this with a self join.

Comment: @CraigRinger can you please answer how? I never care for the complex queries in the past and just used to hibernate.

Comment: Now look at it. Sorry, @ypercube for overwriting your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select l.* 
from location as l                             --- find all locations
where not exists                               --- where there isn't 
      ( select * 
        from location_flag as lf               --- a flag
        where lf.location_id = l.id 
          and lf.flag_id = 1                   --- with 1
          and lf.value = 'YES'                 --- and YES
          and not exists                       --- without 
              ( select *                      
                from location_flag as lf2      --- another flag
                where lf2.location_id = l.id 
                  and lf2.flag_id = 2          --- with 2
                  and lf2.value = 'YES'        --- and YES
              )
      ) ;
```

or:

```
select l.* 
from location as l 
where not exists 
      ( select * 
        from location_flag as lf
        where lf.location_id = l.id 
          and lf.flag_id = 1 
          and lf.value = 'YES'
      )
   or exists
      ( select * 
        from location_flag as lf2
        where lf2.location_id = l.id 
        and lf2.flag_id = 2 
        and lf2.value = 'YES'
      ) ;
```

Comment: you're to eager to help and I'm too lazy to even seek help. You're one of the last good human beings left on this planet. May the force be with you :) thanks.

which one is faster btw?